# Difference between '-std' and '--std' compiler flags

Tags: gcc, compiler-flags

I've noticed that both `-std` and `--std` works for setting the standard for compiling. What is the difference between using a `-` and `--` before `std`?

I've googled and found [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html), but it doesn't seem to mention anything about a single hyphen vs a double hyphen before a `std`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-std=c99` is ok but `-std c99` is an error. `--std c99` is valid as is `--std=c99`. That's the only difference.

You can see that they map to the same action in [opts-common.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/bd3f0a53c07086e978ea4ec00e10a20e4a969c40/gcc/opts-common.c):

```
struct option_map
{
  /* Prefix of the option on the command line.  */
  const char *opt0;
  /* If two argv elements are considered to be merged into one option,
     prefix for the second element, otherwise NULL.  */
  const char *opt1;
  /* The new prefix to map to.  */
  const char *new_prefix;
  /* Whether at least one character is needed following opt1 or opt0
     for this mapping to be used.  (--optimize= is valid for -O, but
     --warn- is not valid for -W.)  */
  bool another_char_needed;
  /* Whether the original option is a negated form of the option
     resulting from this map.  */
  bool negated;
};

static const struct option_map option_map[] =
  {
   ...
    { "--std=", NULL, "-std=", false, false },
    { "--std", "", "-std=", false, false },
   ...
  };
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that!